# Optimizing my code for Broyden's method

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, approximation, iteration

The following code is my attempt of employing [Broyden's method for root finding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%27s_method) on the function $f(x,y)=(e^{xy}-y^2-2,\cos(x+y)+\frac{1}{2})$. Where the first matrix is the Jacobian, then it gets updated using an estimate. So $k[l,k]$ computes the first 12 iterations. However, this program is extremely slow and I am not sure why. Could anyone point out why it is so slow and how I could improve it?

```
k[l_, k_] := Module[{m}, 
  f[{x_, y_}] := {Exp[x y] - y^2 - 2, Cos[x + y] + 1/2};
  h = {Exp[x y] - y^2 - 2, Cos[x + y] + 1/2};
  b = {x, y};
  
  m[0] := {{l}, {k}};
  
  J[0] := D[h, {b}];
  m[n_] := 
   m[n] = N[m[n - 1]] - 
      Inverse[N[J[n - 1]]].N[f[m[n - 1]]] /. {x -> 
       Part[Part[N[m[n - 1]], 1], 1], 
      y -> Part[Part[N[m[n - 1]], 2], 1]};
  J[n_] := 
   J[n] = N[
      J[n - 1]] + ((N[f[m[n]]] - N[f[m[n - 1]]] - 
          N[J[n - 1]].(N[m[n] - m[n - 1]]))/
        Norm[N[m[n] - m[n - 1]]]^2).Transpose[N[m[n]] - N[m[n - 1]]];
  Table[m[a], {a, 1, 12}]]
```

I would appreciate any input.

EDIT: I found some optimization to my code. I removed the redundant $N$ as per a suggestion in the comments. The optimization I found is to deal with numerical matrices form the get go. The original code did everything for arbitrary $x,y$

````
k[l_, k_] := Module[{m}, 
  f[{x_, y_}] := {Exp[x y] - y^2 - 2, Cos[x + y] + 1/2};
  h = {Exp[x y] - y^2 - 2, Cos[x + y] + 1/2};
  b = {x, y};
  
  m[0] := N[{{l}, {k}}];
  
  J[0] := 
   N[D[h, {b}]] /. {x -> Part[Part[m[0], 1], 1], 
     y -> Part[Part[m[0], 2], 1]};
  m[n_] := m[n] = m[n - 1] - LinearSolve[J[n - 1], f[m[n - 1]]];
  J[n_] := 
   J[n] = J[
      n - 1] + ((f[m[n]] - f[m[n - 1]] - J[n - 1].(m[n] - m[n - 1]))/
        Norm[m[n] - m[n - 1]]^2).Transpose[m[n] - m[n - 1]];
  Table[m[a], {a, 1, 15}]]
```
````

Comment: Your code is very hard to follow because of all the brackets, parts, unnecessary `N`s, and in-body function definitions. An iterative algorithm might be better with `Nest`. I'm not familiar with this numerical method but I've rewritten it here: https://pastebin.com/Xhu4n2v8 . It's quite sensitive to the initial value and converges a bit slowly for this function, so I may not have got it right, but you get the gist of it.

Comment: @flinty Since you went to the trouble of writing code and posting it, please post it AS AN ANSWER so it gets preserved with its attached question and everybody can see it.

Comment: @MarcoB the question is about improving the existing code, not rewriting it, so I didn't think it constituted an answer as to why OPs code is slow.

Comment: @flinty I appreciate your input; however, I would like to know what specifically is slowing down my method. Regrading the ```N``` I added so many of them since thought it would cut down some time. Instead of evaluating the terms exactly it would approximate them

Comment: @flinty Including improvements like LinearSolve etc. *is* improving the existing code the *right way*, i.e. by making it more idiomatic, rather than trying to patch it up. Remember that the point is not to answer this question for this user, but to provide something useful for the *next users* as well. A future user might be led here while looking for an implementation of this method, and you have one on hand...

Comment: @MarcoB I did not know that, thank you for letting me know. So I can remove all the $N$'s except at the initial values, correct?

Comment: The idea of Broyden's method is to invert/factorize the initial Jacobian only once in the beginning (e.g. with `LinearSolve`) and to use the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman–Morrison_formula) to deal with the rank-1-updates. At the moment OP's code looks as if the a linear solve were performed in each iteration. (The many linear solves are typically the reason why Newton's method takes so long. Not in dimension, 2 though.)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher That is correct, I am using Linear Solve at each update of the initial Jacobian. I thought newtons method is long in more than 1 dimension since calculating the actual jacobian is hard, so we use the Broyden updating to speed up the process. Are you saying that the algorithm is ok, but it is still pretty slow since it is not using the formula you suggest? I think I found one optimization that makes it work much faster

Comment: I am just saying that you did not implement Broyden's method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is the fact that the values of the Jacobian are kept symbolic at every iteration, so their complexity grows exponentially.

For each iteration `J[n]` should have the value of `{x, y}` updated from `m[n-1]`. I am also unravelling the internal definitions of all those functions, removing the unnecessary `N` calls, and somewhat simplifying the rest of the code:

```
ClearAll[f, k, J, m]
f[{x_, y_}] = {Exp[x y] - y^2 - 2, Cos[x + y] + 1/2};
J[0] = D[f[{x, y}], {{x, y}}];

(* note the replacement of the values of x and y at the end *)
(* that is critical to obtain numerical values for J at each step *)
(* that was the source of your slowdown *)
J[n_] := J[
    n] = (J[n - 
        1] + ((f@m[n] - f@m[n - 1] - J[n - 1].(m[n] - m[n - 1]))/
         Norm[m[n] - m[n - 1]]^2).(m[n] - m[n - 1])) /. 
    Thread[{x, y} -> m[n - 1]];


m[n_] := m[n] = 
  m[n - 1] - (Inverse[J[n - 1]].f@m[n - 1] /. 
     Thread[{x, y} -> m[n - 1]])
```

Let's see a trial run:

```
m[0] = N@{1, 4};
results = Table[m[n], {n, 0, 15}]
ListPlot@Transpose@results
```

> {{1., 4.}, {1.00863, 3.17414}, {0.934639, 3.25276}, {0.886161,
> 3.30122}, {0.852723, 3.33465}, {0.829105, 3.35826}, {0.812153,
> 3.3752}, {0.799845, 3.38751}, {0.790838, 3.39651}, {0.784208,
> 3.40314}, {0.779307, 3.40804}, {0.775673, 3.41167}, {0.772972,
> 3.41437}, {0.770961, 3.41638}, {0.769463, 3.41787}, {0.768345,
> 3.41899}}

[image: convergence plot]

---

The problem still remains that this approach based on matrix inversion at every step is not very efficient, and I am also not sure that it is in the spirit of the method proposed (although I am not familiar with it).

Finally,

```
FindRoot[f[{x, y}], {x, 1}, {y, 4}]

(* Out: {x -> 0.764945, y -> 3.42385} *)
```

is built-in and orders of magnitude faster, of course.